# Regex expression for strings

Tags: regex, string

I need a regex that matches a string with the following specifications:

>
At least one alpha-numeric character, followed by one or zero '?' or one or zero '!', but does not contain both '?' and '!'.
Examples of valid strings: 'xyz', 'zy!', 'Xy?'

I have come up with this so far, which does not work:

```
[0-9]|[a-z] + ?! + ?? ^[^<>]+$
```

Comment: Try `^[A-Za-z0-9]+[?!]?$` See https://regex101.com/r/zObrop/1 or `\b[A-Za-z0-9]+[?!]?(?!\S)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this worked, thank you!

Comment: @Thefourthbird Please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be repeating a character class `[A-Za-z0-9]+` 1+ times followed by matching an optional question or exclamation mark using another character class `[?!]?`

To prevent being part of a larger word you might start the pattern with a wordboundary `\b` and end asserting `(?!\S)` not a non whitespace char on the right.

```
\b[A-Za-z0-9]+[?!]?(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oib3Im/1)

To match the exact string only you might use anchors `^` to assert the start and `$` end of the string.

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+[?!]?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zObrop/1)